# powershell change filename using first 10 characters and mask

Tags: powershell

This script was working fine for a while but I have found that users don't always comply with the correct naming conventions for it to be effective. I have been banging my head trying to modify it but my meager scripting skills are not letting me find a solution.

```
$directory = 'c:\temp'
Get-ChildItem $directory
Dir $directory | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "-"," " }
Dir $directory | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "_"," " }
dir $directory |
    % {rename-item -path $_.fullname -newname ( ($_.name.split(' ')[0..2] -join '-' ) + $_.Extension )}
```

Users place files to be archived in a folder. The files are supposed to be named with a job number at the beginning of the file name so they look like:
99-99-9999 (always 10 characters)
They have the option to put a description behind that job number so the file may look like:

`99-99-9999 - some descrition.txt`

The description will vary and may contain any character after the mandatory beginning. I would like to rename the file using the first 10 characters. I would also like to be able to ensure that the script doesn't run if the first 10 characters are not in this format.

I thought I was on the right track with: `$newname = $list.Name.Substring(0,10)` but I can't get it to work.

Edit- I am one step closer. I have found that this code will change file name using first 10 characters.

```
gci -Path "c:\temp" | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(0,10)}
```

I now need to find a way to filter get-childitems so it only processes objects with my file pattern.

Comment: Why does your script correct files with the wrong name when you say you want to ensure it does not run at all if the name is wrong? Where does `$list` come from, you didn't mention it before. Are you just trying to remove the description, or are you trying to correct the file names?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to loop through 3 times to do your replace and renames. The below code does not account for every iteration of your users data but it is a start.

```
$directory = 'c:\test'

# Get files only
$dirs = Get-ChildItem $directory | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $false}

#loop through each file name
foreach ($d in $dirs){

    $jobNum = $d.Name.Substring(0,10) –replace("_", "-") 
    $comment = ($d.Name.Substring(10, $d.Name.length - 10))
    Rename-Item $d.FullName "$jobNum - $comment"

}
```

Comment: That works great...now I just need a way to ensure that the script doesnt run if the file is does not match the pattern 99-99-9999.

Answer (score 2):

Have you met regular expressions? Pattern matching masks.

```
^ matches from the start of a string
\d matches a digit 0-9
{2} matches something twice
```

So:

```
gci 'c:\temp' |? Name -match '^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}' | ren -N { $_.SubString(0,10)+$_.Extension }
```

Will match your desired pattern and rename them to drop the description, ignoring the rest.

Or:

```
gci 'c:\temp' |? Name -match '^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}' | ren -N { 
    ($_.Name -replace '^(\d\d).(\d\d).(\d\d\d\d).*','$1-$2-$3')+$_.Extension
}
```

Will allow any other character between the numbers , e.g. Underscores.